# How to insert value in already created Database table through pandas `df.to_sql()`

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm creating new table then inserting values in it because the tsv file doesn't have headers so i need to create table structure first then insert the value. I'm trying to insert the value in database table which is been created. I'm using `df.to_sql` function to insert `tsv` values into database table but its creating table but it's not inserting values in that table and its not giving any type of error either.

I have tried to create new table through `sqalchemy` and `insert` value it worked but it didn't worked for already created table.

```
conn, cur = create_conn()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:Shubham@123@localhost:5432/walmart')

create_query = '''create table if not exists new_table(
                "item_id" TEXT, "product_id" TEXT, "abstract_product_id" TEXT, 
           "product_name" TEXT, "product_type" TEXT, "ironbank_category" TEXT, 
          "primary_shelf" TEXT, apparel_category" TEXT, "brand" TEXT)'''

cur.execute(create_query)
conn.commit()
file_name = 'new_table'
new_file = "C:\\Users\\shubham.shinde\\Desktop\\wallll\\new_file.txt"
data = pd.read_csv(new_file, delimiter="\t", chunksize=500000, error_bad_lines=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dtype="unicode", iterator=True)
with open(file_name + '_bad_rows.txt', 'w') as f1:
    sys.stderr = f1
    for df in data:
        df.to_sql('new_table', engine, if_exists='append')
data.close()
```

I want to insert values from `df.to_sql()` into database table

Comment: What is the error? Please share some data as well.

Comment: can you try printing `df` before `df.to_sql`?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal `df ` is been printing

Comment: @SupratimHaldar it's not showing error the problem is it's not loading data into table

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain if this argument works with `postgresql`, but I had a similar issue when doing it on `mssql`. `.to_sql()` already creates the table in the first argument of the method in `new_table`. The `if_exists = append` also doesn't check for duplicate values. If data in `new_file` is overwritten, or run through your function again, it will just add to the table. As to why you're seeing the table name, but not seeing the data in it, might be due to the size of the `df`. Try setting `fast_executemany=True` as the second argument of the `create_engine`.

My suggestion, get rid of `create_query`, and handle the data types after `to_sql()`. Once the SQL table is created, you can use your actual SQL table, and join against this staging table for duplicate testing. The non-duplicates can be written to the actual table, converting datatypes on `UPDATE` to match the tables data type structure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for late reply i have found solution for this problem i am adding header in the csv file while reading the csv file and then uploading that file to database that solved my problem. `col_name = ['1st_column',  '2nd_column', '3rd_column']`     and then reading the csv file                                             ```data = pd.read_csv(new_file, delimiter="\t", chunksize=500000, error_bad_lines=False, names=col_name, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dtype="unicode", iterator=True, header=None)
```